# Using Perl LWP::UserAgent I get a response on port 443 but not from port 8443

Tags: perl, user-agent, lwp

I am using LWP::UserAgent to check the response from a server. I get a response from port 443 but I am not able to get any response from port 8443.

When I use cURL for Windows I get a response code from both ports.

Please help me.

Comment: There is no difference for LWP between these two ports. Please show the code you use for accessing the two websites.

Comment: Are you using HTTPS? Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

This example program (adapted from perldoc lwpcook) shows how to connect with a different port

It also allows turning off of the SSL verify, in case you have a home brew cert that is causing a problem

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$port = $ARGV[1] || 443;
$host = $ARGV[0] || 'pause.perl.org';
$verify =$ARGV[2] || 0;
use LWP::UserAgent;
$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => $verify});;

#$ua->agent("$0/0.1 " . $ua->agent);
$ua->agent("Mozilla/8.0");    # pretend we are very capable browser

$req = HTTP::Request->new( GET => "https://$host:$port" );
$req->header( 'Accept' => 'text/html' );

# send request
$res = $ua->request($req);

# check the outcome
if ( $res->is_success ) {
    print $res->decoded_content;
}
else {
    print "Error: " . $res->status_line . "\n";
}
```

Comment: This is wrong since both HTTPS and port 443 are the same

Comment: The program in the answer takes an optional arg of the port number to use and this defaults to 443.  The point however of the program is to allow HTTPS traffic on a port that is not 443.  The question suggested 8443